# How do I compare a variable with the type 'float' with a constant?

Tags: python

I tried to put up this code and it doesn't seems to be working, apparently `while` doesn't support comparing a variable with a float, interesting.

```
while input < 0.01:
    input = get_int("Change owed: ")
```

When I submit my code into the compiler, it gives me an error that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/pset6/cash.py", line 4, in <module>
    while input < 0.01:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
```

I'm not sure what the error means. But how could I fix my code?

Comment: Don't name your variable `input`. That's a Python built-in function.

Comment: `input` is not a float, as the error message is telling you.

Comment: "how do I compare input, a float..."—The error message is telling you that `input` is not a float; it's a function. Why do you think it is a float?

Comment: And even after `get_int()` it will be an `int`, not a `float`.

Comment: You're not asking for input until *after* you test the value.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few good responses here. Putting them together:

1. You are setting the 'input' inside the function, that will not work (unless you have cut out the code that would make it make sense).
2. Change the name of 'input' variable to something else. You want to avoid conflicts with default/built in python functions.
3. You are not comparing equivalent types. To fix this, you need to put the input into a float like so;

   ```
   float(inputVarName)
   ```

Which might end up looking like this

```
inputVar = **Take Input**
while float(inputVar) < 0.01:
     #Do something
```

However, I don't really understand why you are doing this in a while loop. It may make sense in your situation, but it is not clear why from what you have posted.

Comment: @BraveGamerTV - Yeah, it can be hard figuring out how to use this site effectively. Its pretty notorious for not being forgiving to new people. My assumption for why this was downvoted, is because its a relatively simple question, which should be solvable by some googling.
I understand though, it can be difficult to find the solution when you aren't super familiar with the topic. Can be that way for veterans too, but they will generally persevere with google and other resources before asking a question.

Please accept answer if you found it useful and resolved you issue. Otherwise, ask more